# Can genetic algorithms be used for statistical inference?

Tags: machine-learning, inference, genetic-algorithms

Is it possible to use genetic algorithms for (pseudo-) statistical inference? I.e., something like constructing confidence intervals from stable generations?

I hope my question make sense & apologize if it doesn't. I come from a self-taught stats background, and have only ever heard of genetic algorithms very recently. I've got the idea about using GA's for inference after reading about MCMC methods for Bayesian estimation. I've tried to search around for it but I can't find any papers.

Comment: A genetic algorithm can be viewed as yet another Markov Chain in Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) of the whole generation. For that reason, it inherits the properties of MCMC. In practice, however the mixing speed of the genetic algorithm may not be good.

Comment: @stans, how would you propose using a GA in an MCMC context? It is an interesting thought. For instance, one could consider using a GA as the "proposal" distribution within Metropolis-Hastings... but this certainly complicates the acceptance probability and it is not clear to me how one would reconcile this.

Comment: genetic algorithms are slow. in statistics we tend to avoid being forced to use such slow tools, because we can make assumptions about the model we are working with, that makes computations easy and consistent.

Comment: @knrumsey You are right. This is exactly what *1 step* in a genetic algorithm is, a proposal. And the acceptance probability is the probability that the overall fitness of the proposed new generation (or a subset of it, depending on the specifications) is higher than the overall fitness of the current generation (or a subset of it). Having that said, I am not necessarily proposing to use GA within the MCMC framework. As a Markov chain they may or may not be a convenient tool. The properties may be difficult to study and the convergence speed may be far from the optimum. (cont)

Comment: ... Depends on the problem, I guess... Still, it is worth mentioning that some stochastic optimization algorithms can be rephrased as MCMC.

Comment: @stans, but it seems highly unlikely that the GA proposal will be symmetric... therefore the acceptance probability must also include the ratio $q(\theta|\theta')/q(\theta'|\theta)$. It is unclear to me how you would capture that.

Comment: @stans would GA also be slower for high-dimensional problems? I'm coming at this completely naive, but I was just thinking that, e.g., taking the HMC algorithm as an example, it may be easier to estimate K parameters simultaneously as traits in GA compared to estimating the path across a K-dimensional surface in HMC

Comment: @Adam B As almost any method, GA would be slower in high dimensions. However, it would not suffer from the curse of dimensionality as much as many other optimization alternatives.

Comment: @knrumsey Good point. A modification is necessary. One way of making GA MCMC is postulating that we use the fittest K members from a given generation but do not require that generation (t+1) be fitter than generation t overall... GA is a Markov chain on the space of possible states of the whole generation. As long as the number of members in a generation is fixed, the Markov chain is finite. Also, if mutation is allowed with positive probability, the Markov chain is aperiodic and recurrent. A finite, recurrent, aperiodic Markov chain converges to a stationary distribution. (cont.)

Comment: ... In Layman's terms, the stationary distribution is a kind of Sparta, where most people are beautiful but the weakest few are killed off regularly. The fittest member of such a prominent Greek town should be fine for optimization purposes (as long as the population size is substantial).